# How to use pattern matching to apply a function to specific elements of a matrix

Tags: pattern-matching, pure-function

I have a 3x3 matrix

```
testweightedgraph = {{{}, {p, q, pq, pq}, {}}, {{p, q, pq, 
pq}, {q}, {}}, {{}, {}, {}}};
```

whose elements are (possibly empty) lists.

I would like to apply the pure function

```
1 - Apply[Times, 1 - #] &
```

to every nonempty element of the matrix, leaving the empty elements exactly as they are. The result I want is this:

```
{{{}, {1 - (1 - p) (1 - pq)^2 (1 - q)}, {}}, {{1 - (1 - p) (1 - 
   pq)^2 (1 - q)}, {q}, {}}, {{}, {}, {}}}
```

If I use

```
Map[{1 - Apply[Times, 1 - #]} &, testweightedgraph, {2}]
```

then I get

```
{{{0}, {1 - (1 - p) (1 - pq)^2 (1 - q)}, {0}}, {{1 - (1 - p) (1 - 
   pq)^2 (1 - q)}, {q}, {0}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}}}
```

which is perfect, except that all instances of `{0}` should be replaced by `{}`.

Rather than patching the result, by somehow replacing `{0}`s by `{}`s, I would like to get it right in the first place.

One option seems to be to use `Position` and feed its results to `MapAt`. This has two disadvantages for me: 1) Perhaps `Position` needs to be told exactly what to look for, and cannot be asked to look for elements satisfying a pattern (such as, in this case "not being the empty list"). 2) If we are going to have to use pattern matching anyway, then isn't there a more direct way to do it, without using `Position` or `MapAt` ?

I have studied the tutorials on Pattern Matching but I confess I find it very hard to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Design a function that ignores empty lists:

```
f[{}] = {};
f[{a__}] := {1 - Times @@ (1 - {a})}
Map[f, testweightedgraph, {2}]
```

> ```
> {
>  {{}, {1 - (1 - p) (1 - pq)^2 (1 - q)}, {}}, 
>  {{1 - (1 - p) (1 - pq)^2 (1 - q)}, {q}, {}},
>  {{}, {}, {}}
> }
> ```

Comment: @Simon note the minor correction I just added (`f[{a__}]` rather than `f[a__]`). It might be better suited to handling certain corner cases.

Comment: Thank you ! Yes when I tried your first set of code the nonempty lists were simply wrapped in {}, without the subtraction, multiplication and subtraction being performed. Your new code works perfectly for me. This serves two purposes: Solving my problem and also giving me a good example from which to start understanding pattern matching. Very many thanks !

Answer (score 3):

This is the sort of thing `If[]` was meant for:

```
Map[If[# =!= {}, 1 - Apply[Times, 1 - #], #] &, testweightedgraph, {2}]
```

Comment: That is also a very nice answer, thank you J. M. I like the piecewise definition of LLIAMnYP's answer, and I like that J. M.'s doesn't define a named function. P.S. J. M. since I want my matrix elements to be lists, I have added some curly braces to your code: `Map[If[# =!= {}, {1 - Apply[Times, 1 - #]}, #] &, 
  testweightedgraph, {2}]`

Answer (score 2):

With respect to your list of disadvantages about using `Position` to resolve the problem

*Perhaps `Position` needs to be told exactly what to look for, and cannot be asked to look for elements satisfying a pattern (such as, in this case "**not being the empty list**")*

I think that you can use a general pattern to extract non empty lists

```
testweightedgraph = {{{}, {p, q, pq, pq}, {}}, {{p, q, pq, 
    pq}, {q}, {}}, {{}, {}, {}}}

Position[testweightedgraph, {x__}, {2}]
(* {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}} *)
```

and then as you suggested use `MapAt`

```
MapAt[{1 - Apply[Times, 1 - #]} &, testweightedgraph, 
 Position[testweightedgraph, {a__}, {2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You are absolutely right, Jack - thank you very much for answering ! It's so nice to have many different ways of doing the same thing. I can imagine each of these might be preferable to the others, in the right situation.